# How do I compare the counts after a group by in Pandas for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, count, entity-attribute-value, pandas-groupby

I have an EAV table loaded into a Pandas dataframe. I used a group by to count the occurrences of each field of each entity. I'd like to compare the count of prices and product names, extract ones where the counts are unequal and extract them for processing (a and c in this case). 
Currently the count also appears on a different row to the headers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
                        Count
Entity  Attribute
 a      ProductName      10
        Price            11
 b      ProductName       2
        Price             2
 c      ProductName       3
        Price             4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first step is [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `Entities` to `columns`:

```
df1 = df['Count'].unstack(0)
print (df1)
Entity        a  b  c
Attribute            
Price        11  2  4
ProductName  10  2  3
```

Then select columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and compare rows by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`), last filter columns by `boolean mask`:

```
print (df1.loc['Price'].ne(df1.loc['ProductName']))
Entity
a     True
b    False
c     True
dtype: bool

df2 = df1.loc[:, df1.loc['Price'].ne(df1.loc['ProductName'])]
print (df2)
Entity        a  c
Attribute         
Price        11  4
ProductName  10  3
```

Similar if need only column names:

```
cols = df1.columns[df1.loc['Price'].ne(df1.loc['ProductName'])].tolist()
print (cols)
['a', 'c']
```